# Django FOREIGN KEY constraint failed after submitting form

Tags: django

Good day, just learning Django since 3 day now. After typing something in the form, clicking the submit button, I want the title to be assigned to a user. But I'm getting this error:

```
IntegrityError at /todo/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/todo/
Django Version:     4.0.1
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    

FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

In the Admin Dashboard, the form is also saved and "Author" dropdown is displayed, but no user is assigned to the author.

// models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class Todos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

\forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# check for unique email & username

from .models import Todos

User = get_user_model()


class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "id": "user-password"
            }
        )
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Confirm Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "id": "user-confirm-password"
            }
        )
    )


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control"
        }))
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "id": "user-password"
            }
        )
    )


class TodosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Todos

        fields = [
            'title'
        ]
```

\views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
from .forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm, TodosForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


User = get_user_model()


def signup_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = form.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        except:
            user = None
        if user != None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/todo")
        else:
            request.session['register_error'] = 1  # 1 == True
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/")

    return render(request, "signup.html", {"form": form})


def signin_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user != None:
            # user is valid and active -> is_active
            # request.user == user
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            # attempt = request.session.get("attempt") or 0
            # request.session['attempt'] = attempt + 1
            # return redirect("/invalid-password")
            request.session['invalid_user'] = 1  # 1 == True

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("/")

    return render(request, "signin.html", {"form": form})


def signout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # request.user == Anon User
    return redirect("/signin")


@login_required
def todo_view(request):
    form = TodosForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.author = request.user
        instance.save()

    return render(request, "todo.html", {"form": form})
```

Comment: Are you sure the Todos model you share here is the one you have migrated to your database?

Comment: Yes, I deleted all my migrations and did again

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

How can I check if it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom user model?  <s>Your Todos model is referencing a user, `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` for your `author` field, but your User model does not seem to be connected to this.</s>  Are you using django's default user model, or a custom model.  If you want to create a custom user model with email as a username, checkout https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-custom-user-model.   Otherwise, try:

```py
author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

But if this User model you've created is not a custom model, then I don't understand why you can't use django's regular user model as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/).

**EDIT**
There is no reason to have

```py
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Django's `User` model already has fields for username, email, and password.  If that's all you want there is no need to [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).  That is probably what causes the problems.  I would also add that there is no need for you to have `User = get_user_model()` i forms.py, where I can't see you using the User model at all.  And in your views.py you already have `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues for hours and no answer worked.

Just comment the attribute of the model in my case the `author` field and `run migrations` and uncomment the `author` field the and run migrations again.

I wish could tell you what the problem  was but I don't know but this solved the issue I was facing.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32962110)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).